ORY Kratos integration with UAE Pass as Social Sign In
I my project we are using Ory Kratos and Hydra. Able to successfully register and login user via self service flows.
Now, we want to add social sign flow. I have tested this with Github, and it works seamlessly. We want to add support for UAE Pass.
But when coming to Uae Pass, they do not expose /.wellKnown/openid-configuration endpoint, which Kratos need to get details of other endpoints and claims.
As per comments in https://github.com/ory/kratos/blob/master/selfservice/strategy/oidc/provider_config.go
It says we can use for auth_url and token_url, in case when the OAuth2 / OpenID Connect server is not supporting OpenID Connect Discovery.
It means Kratos should be able to support UAE Pass.
So, I have tried with below config for use pass, and still getting error.
oidc:
      config:
        providers:
          - client_id: sandbox_stage
            client_secret: sandbox_stage
            id: u6ZEcp7W
           #have tried both with empty string and deleting the entry completely
            issuer_url: ""
            auth_url: https://stg-id.uaepass.ae/idshub/authorize
            token_url: https://stg-id.uaepass.ae/idshub/token
            label: uea-pass
            mapper_url: https://storage.googleapis.com/bac-gcs-production/0d878eabc6b5fb37a6e1f35ab40c9936c2306fa273c97c452188059e2cbde2ed52bcf11287710f14ab4df68ec8afe1512807ef9d853d71b1ece53fe8656b9497.jsonnet
            provider: generic
            scope:
              - urn:uae:digitalid:profile:general urn:uae:digitalid:profile:general:profileType urn:uae:digitalid:profile:general:unifiedId
            claims_source: userinfo
      enabled: true

{
  "id": "2c48fa02-142b-4ec2-9be5-56ae4d97b05d",
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "status": "Internal Server Error",
    "reason": "Unable to initialize OpenID Connect Provider: Get \"/.well-known/openid-configuration\": unsupported protocol scheme \"\"",
    "message": "An internal server error occurred, please contact the system administrator"
  },
  "created_at": "2024-04-25T11:34:37.346379Z",
  "updated_at": "2024-04-25T11:34:37.346379Z"
}

Also, please clarify what does below comment on issuer_url in provider_config.go  mean ?
    // IssuerURL is the OpenID Connect Server URL. You can leave this empty if `provider` is not set to `generic`.
    // If set, neither `auth_url` nor `token_url` are required.

And in case where server is not supporting OpenID Connect Discovery, what should be the value for issuer_url ?
